# How can i complete to fill the array?

Tags: ruby

I want to complete to fill the array, for example i already have an array like this:

[1,2,3,4,5] and now over this i want to complete to fill the array until 10 with an value 9

i need this output

```
[1,2,3,4,5,9,9,9,9,9]
```

i was trying with a loop

but i dont know if there are another best way to do this

Comment: You are more likely to receive help when demonstrating that you've tried something as opposed to just asking for the answer

Comment: @Tom i updated my question see please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Array.new`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.0/Array.html#method-c-new) can create an array with a default value and size.

So, if you know that the resulting length should be `10` and the value to fill the missing elements is `9`, you can calculate how many elements you need from the difference between 10 and the length of elements in `[1,2,3,4,5]`, and create a new array from both arrays using [`Array#+`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.0/Array.html#method-i-2B):

```
arr + Array.new(10 - arr.size, 9)
# [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9]
```

Answer (score 6):

If you want to fill the array to a specific length with a specific value, you can use the aptly named [`Array#fill`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Array.html#method-i-fill) method:

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5]

a.fill(9, a.length..9)
#=>  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9]
```